# Прошу поддержать предложение сообщества на Area 51 для TeX/LaTeX

Tags: обсуждение, тематика

Я пользуюсь системой `TeX/LaTeX`, и очень часто у меня возникают вопросы по её использованию. К сожалению, очень много справочной информации по данной системе возможно найти лишь на английском языке, и мне требуется дополнительное время для её понимания. Я смог найти лишь 2 хороших русскоязычных ресурса по данной теме:

- этот сайт (который, как я гляжу, не сильно популярен у `TeX`овцев)
- раздел форума dxdy.ru: [TeXнические обсуждения](http://dxdy.ru/texnicheskie-obsuzhdeniya-f33.html)

На последнем не всегда имеется возможность получить требуемую информацию оперативно. Так что мне хотелось бы иметь Q&A-сайт на русском специально для вопросов по тематике TeX/LaTeX.

Прошу поддержать моё предложение: [TeX/LaTeX in Russian](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/106328/tex-latex-in-russian)

Comment: большой вопрос, найдется ли для такого сайта достаточное количество пользователей?

Comment: Скорее всего, предложение будет отклонено модераторами, как "not currently feasible", т. к. это сообщество не на английском языке. Так что даже поддержка ничего не определит. Но всё равно стоит время от времени напоминать компании, что мы очень хотим новые русскоязычные сообщества :)

Comment: @D-side, а мы точно хотим? Лично я хочу впихнуть всё в ruSO :)

Comment: @Qwertiy да? Вопросы юридического, кулинарного (SA), психологического (Parenting), профессионального (Workplace) и других характеров тоже?

Comment: @D-side, ну не на столько же всё))

Comment: @Qwertiy вот вы сами и ответили на свой вопрос :)

Comment: @D-side только не модераторами, а сотрудниками SE. :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin а разве не только они являются модераторами на Area51? Да, я слабо разбираюсь в тамошних порядках :)

Comment: @D-side я там ниже приводил пример: использование [tag:bash] и [tag:ssh] для заваривания кофе считается кулинарией? )

Comment: @D-side а я тоже не разбираюсь. Просто так уточняю, что это не наш [tag:модераторский-произвол] будет.

Comment: @NickVolynkin я скорее про вопросы вида "как удалить лишнюю воду при жарке замороженных овощей", которые к программированию не относятся. Ваш-то к кулинарии, пожалуй, относится, но лишь предметной областью, не сутью :)

Comment: Автор, скажите, как вам вариант развивать эту тему здесь? Есть ли вопросы, возражения, сомнения? В чём нужна помощь? Расскажите пожалуйста, мы постараемся помочь. Мы вообще заинтересованы в привлечении специалистов и некотором расширении тематики.

Comment: @D-side, свершилось: `closed as not currently feasible by Robert Cartaino♦ 3 hours ago
This proposal requires technical or personnel resources that Stack Exchange currently lacks in order to proceed. If these circumstances change, we will open a new discussion to announce that.`

Answer (score 13):

Вы прямо сейчас находитесь на сайте, который хотите создать, потому что [tex](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tex)/[latex](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/latex) — это

1. Язык разметки, который явно входит в тематику Stack Overflow на русском языке наравне с другими языками разметки: [html](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html), [markdown](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/markdown), [reStructuredText](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html), [AsciiDoc](http://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc/) и прочими.
2. Инструмент технической документации, которая тоже входит в допустимую тематику сайта.

Вопросов по TeX задаётся пока немного, но нужно просто привлекать новых участников. Очень рад, что вас интересует эта тема. Возьмите метку «под свою опеку» здесь, начните её развивать. Например, можно:

1. Перевести хорошие вопросы с англоязычного сайта или из других источников (где лицензия позволяет).
2. Написать собственный исчерпывающий ответ по какой-нибудь интересной и важной проблеме.
3. Пригласить участников из других сообществ задавать вопросы и отвечать на них здесь.
4. Привести в порядок метки:

   1. Сделать для них хорошие описания.
   2. Перебрать поиском вопросы и развесить метки, где их ещё нет.
5. Найти (или написать) хороший ответ про TeX и опубликовать ссылку на нём в соцсетях или блоге, чтобы привлечь читателей.

---

Кстати, все предложения по созданию локализованных сайтов, кроме Stack Overflow и посвящённых изучению языка, в настоящее время отклоняются. [Такова политика компании](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20988/internationalization-state-of-the-stack-se-2-0-sites-edition). Поверьте, на новом отдельно взятом сайте участников было бы существенно меньше, чем здесь. И активность тоже была бы минимальная.

---

В общем и целом — было бы желание, средства найдутся. Есть, например, такой план:

1. Написать серию базовых вопросов и ответов о том, для каких задач хорош TeX и как легко начать его использовать.
2. Написать об этом пост на Мете вроде «TeX: новая тематика на ruSO» и прикрепить его [важно](/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be).
3. Profit: программисты и сисадмины читают и впечатляются, как хорошо писать документацию в ТеХе (особенно если сейчас пишут в каком-нибудь Word или ещё хуже). Сообщество русскоязычных пользователей растёт, база решений растёт, <s>все радуются, поют и танцуют со слонами, нарисованными с помощью LaTeX.</s> ;)

Comment: Я думаю вопрос возник из-за того, что на английском есть [отдельный сайт](http://tex.stackexchange.com/), не входящий в enSO.

Comment: @alexolut у них там много отдельных сайтов, не входящих в enSO, и это доставляет им немало проблем. По крайней мере, разделение SO и SF совершенно нечёткое. Множество меток есть там и там.

Comment: @alexolut или вот [tag:bash]. Если я хочу сложить два числа на баше, то вопрос на SO. Если я хочу админить сервер, то на SF. А если [кофе сварить](http://bash.im/quote/436725) — то на SU.

Comment: Я не утверждаю, что разделение хорошо/плохо, просто привёл возможную причину, по которой ТС задал вопрос.

Comment: @alexolut  понял )

Comment: @alexout Я скажу больше: всё, что мне приходилось искать по `LaTeX`'у, встречалось мне именно на этом сайте. На английском SO ничего не было.

Comment: @Byulent что вполне понятно - с английской версии много что перенесли на TeX.SE.

Comment: @Byulent когда сайт выделяли, все вопросы с enSO перенесли на него и с тех пор на enSO наверняка TeX – оффтопик.

Comment: Кстати, надо будет добавить интерпретацию Латеха в модуль отображения сообщений. Иначе придётся иллюстрировать вопросы через скриншоты. Latex-разметку можно оформлять через `<!-- -->`, по аналогии со сниппетами. Для добавления заготовки разметки можно добавить соответствующую кнопку на панель.

Comment: @Arhad, это та, которая на math? Говорят, тяжеловесная штука.